# How to switch to main window after closing a windows alert box in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium 3.7.1 and firefox latest version 67.0.2, I am actually trying to switch back to my home page after clicking a windows based popup(clicked Ok using AutoIT script). But after the popup closes I cannot switch back to the first window(i.. the home page). In all, there are two windows which are opened.

I have using the code below to switch back to the home page without closing the parent window as I could not take the control back to the parent page. Recently, we had an upgrade in our project before that the code was working fine.

```
public void switchToNewWindow(int windowNumber) {
    Set<String> s = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> ite = s.iterator();
    int i = 1;
    while (ite.hasNext() && i < 10) {
        String popupHandle = ite.next().toString();
        driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        System.out.println("Window title is : " + driver.getTitle());
        if (i == windowNumber)
            break;
        i++;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following output:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Browsing context has been discarded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

//here, your action to bring up a new window
driver.click    

for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        if(!winHandle.equals(mainWindow)) {
            driver.close();
        }
}

//switch to main window
driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
```

Comment: Thanks @Frian I will check and let you know

Comment: Welcome, glad it worked, if you can please ***upvote*** too my answer :) feel free

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

You probably don't need to use `AutoIt` you can accept the alert with:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); 

driver.switchTo().alert(); 

alert.accept();
```

Just use [`switchTo().defaultContent()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#defaultContent--):

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the issue is if it is a windows popup the driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); or the code that I posted isn't working but if there is no windows popup and we are simply switching the windows then the code which I shared as well the defaultcontent is working

Comment: No. I how will that help as it will take me back to the previous frame I think correct me if I am wrong. Here, all I want is to switch back to the first window after clicking the windows popup which is in the second window.

Comment: @titli0216 try one more... I haven't use it... but try! `driver.getUIWindowLocator().switchToFirstWindow();`

Comment: I am getting a red line under getUIWindowLocater. Am I missing anything here?